# replace string in a file with value from another file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, awk

I have two files. One of them defines a set of number-value pairs as follows (**fileA**):

```
 1  asm
 2  assert
 3  bio
 4  bootasm
 5  bootmain
 6  buf
 7  cat
 8  console
 9  defs
10  echo
```

The other file contains a bunch of value pairings, as follows (**fileB**):

```
bio types
bio defs
bio param
bio spinlock
bio buf
bootasm asm
bootasm memlayout
bootasm mmu
bootmain types
bootmain elf
bootmain x86
bootmain memlayout
cat types
cat stat
cat user
```

I want to write a script that replaces the values on file B with their corresponding numbers from file A.
It does not matter if it generates a new file or changes the existing file B.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}{$1=a[$1];}1' fileA fileB
```

NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next} => This is true when the fileA is processed. An associative array is formed where the index is the 2nd column with the 1st column as its value.

{$1=a[$1];} => When the second file is processed, Replace the 1st column with the appropriate value stored in the array.

1 => Print every line.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|^\s*\(\S*\)\s*\(.*\)$|/^\2\\>/s//\1/|' fileA | sed -f - fileB
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note the solution by @Guru doesn't work if you have undefined strings in fileB column one, for example:

fileB

```
...
name user
name system
```

will output:

```
...
 user
 system
```

The string "name" in this case will be truncated. If all rows are matched it works fine.