# replace strings with lines from another text file by matching patterns

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

I have a file with a correspondence key -> value:

```
sort keyFile.txt | head
ENSMUSG00000000001  ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3
ENSMUSG00000000003  ENSMUSG00000000003_Pbsn
ENSMUSG00000000003  ENSMUSG00000000003_Pbsn
ENSMUSG00000000028  ENSMUSG00000000028_Cdc45
ENSMUSG00000000028  ENSMUSG00000000028_Cdc45
ENSMUSG00000000028  ENSMUSG00000000028_Cdc45
ENSMUSG00000000031  ENSMUSG00000000031_H19
ENSMUSG00000000031  ENSMUSG00000000031_H19
ENSMUSG00000000031  ENSMUSG00000000031_H19
ENSMUSG00000000031  ENSMUSG00000000031_H19
```

And I would like to replace every correspondence of "key" with the "value" in the temp.txt:

```
head temp.txt
ENSMUSG00000000001:001  515
ENSMUSG00000000001:002  108
ENSMUSG00000000001:003  64
ENSMUSG00000000001:004  45
ENSMUSG00000000001:005  58
ENSMUSG00000000001:006  63
ENSMUSG00000000001:007  46
ENSMUSG00000000001:008  11
ENSMUSG00000000001:009  13
ENSMUSG00000000003:001  0
```

The result should be:

```
out.txt
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:001    515
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:002    108
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:003    64
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:004    45
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:005    58
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:006    63
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:007    46
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:008    11
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:009    13
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:001    0
```

I have tried a few variations following [this AWK example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13079914/1274242) but as you can see the result is not what I expected:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next}{$1=a[$1];}1' keyFile.txt temp.txt | head
 515
 108
 64
 45
 58
 63
 46
 11
 13
 0
```

My guess is that column 1 of temp does not match 'exactly' column 1 of keyValues. Could someone please help me with this?

R/python/sed solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use awk command like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next} {
   split($1, b, ":");
   if (b[1] in a)
       print a[b[1]] ":" b[2], $2;
   else
       print $0;
 }' keyFile.txt temp.txt
```

Comment: This is fantastic @anubhava. I am still trying to understand all the bits of the command but it worked. Thanks.

Comment: +1 ... just for fun --> `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{split($1, b, ":");print (b[1] in a)?a[b[1]]":"b[2] FS $2:$0}' keyFile.txt temp.txt`

Comment: @JS웃: Thanks so much. As always you have a knack of shortening these things by using ternary operator :P

Comment: You're always welcome. Just bringing true meaning of one-liner to the table. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another awk option

```
awk -F: 'NR == FNR{split($0, a, " "); x[a[1]]=a[2]; next}{print x[$1]":"$2}' keyFile.txt temp.txt
```

Comment: Hope you've tried to run this one. Doesn't give the expected output.

Comment: you solution fails to deal with the 1st line of the file: awk 'NR == FNR {a[$1]=$2; next}{FS=":"; print(a[$1]":"$2)}' keyFile.txt temp.txt | head
:515
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:002 108
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:003 64
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:004 45
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:005 58
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:006 63
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:007 46
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:008 11
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:009 13
ENSMUSG00000000003_Pbsn:001 0

Comment: @anubhava you are a faster commenter than I am :) I posted before seeing that you already had.

Comment: @anubhava, and fridaymeetssunday, thanks for the catch. Fixed. It's an abominable hack but best i can do

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$sed -nr '$!N;/^(.*)\n\1$/!bk;D;:k;s#\S+\s+(\w+)_(\w+)#/^\1/s/(\\w+)(:\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)/\\1_\2\\2 \\3/p#;P;s/^(.*)\n//' keyfile.txt|sed -nrf - temp.txt
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:001 515
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:002 108
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:003 64
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:004 45
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:005 58
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:006 63
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:007 46
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:008 11
ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:009 13
ENSMUSG00000000003_Pbsn:001 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` version:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}
{sub(/[^:]+/,a[substr($1,1,index($1,":")-1)])}1' keyFile.txt temp.txt
```