# replace terms with associated abbreviations from other file, in case of matching

Tags: macos, unix, awk, terminal

I have two files:
1. Pattern file = pattern.txt
2. File containing different terms = terms.txt

pattern.txt contain two columns, separated by `;`
In the first column I have several terms and in the second column abbreviations,
associated to the first column, same line.

terms.txt contain single words and terms defined by single words but also
by a combination of words.

pattern.txt

```
Berlin;Brln
Barcelona;Barcln
Checkpoint Charly;ChckpntChrl
Friedrichstrasse;Fridrchstr
Hall of Barcelona;HllOfBarcln
Paris;Prs
Yesterday;Ystrdy
```

terms.txt

```
Berlin  
The Berlinale ended yesterday  
Checkpoint Charly is still in Friedrichstrasse  
There will be a fiesta in the Hall of Barcelona  
Paris is a very nice city
```

The target is to replace terms with standardised abbreviations and to find out which terms
have no abbreviation.
As result I would like to have two files.
The first file is a new terms file, with terms replaced by abbreviations where it could be replaced.
The second file containing a list with all terms that doesn't have an abbreviation.
The output is case insensitive, I don't make difference between "`The`" and "`the`".

new_terms.txt

```
Brln  
The Berlinale ended Ystrdy  
ChckpntChrl is still in Fridrchstr  
There will be a fiesta in the HllOfBarcln  
Prs is a very nice city
```

terms_without_abbreviations.txt

```
a  
be  
Berlinale  
city  
ended  
fiesta  
in  
is  
nice  
of  
still  
The  
There  
very  
will
```

I will appreciate your help and thanks in advance for your time and hints!

Comment: What did you try for yourself? Post your attempt here.

Comment: I'm using the terminal jus a few times a year and I'm not very experienced. Tried [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321910/replace-strings-with-lines-from-another-text-file-by-matching-patterns?noredirect=1&lq=1) but doesn't match my case.

Comment: You have to remember, SO community helps you out if you post your attempt and fail ( it is not a problem) so that we can help you out. People can't just write free code for you. No disrespect meant!

Comment: Because I highly respect the knowledge in this forum, I'm looking for help here. I had several attempts, but can't solve the problem. To mention one attempt, I can replace some of the terms, the problem is the result I have ist just the abbreviations.  `awk -F";" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$1=a[$1];}1' pattern.txt terms.txt > new_terms.txt`

Comment: ok fair enough, would it hurt  not to have spaces in both the files, i.e. `Checkpoint Charly` to be `Checkpoint-Charly`, do you have control of the files or its not possible?

Comment: I can't control that.

Comment: I don't have it in me to solve this in `Awk` if it has spaces, but can you just use shell script run under `bash`? Or need it in `Awk`

Comment: I can use `bash`, no problem! I just try to avoid using `sed`, because at `OS X` the behaviour of `sed` is different.

Comment: Nah, it chokes on spaces again. Tough luck!

Comment: I can't control how the terms will enter the file. Some terms will be connected by `-` and some not, while the words in the terms are using spaces. This doesn't mean the intended sense is the same, even if both terms use same words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly what you need:

```
BEGIN { FS=";"; }
FNR==NR { dict[tolower($1)] = $2; next }
{
    line = "";
    count = split($0, words, / +/);
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        key = tolower(words[i]);
        if (key in dict) {
            words[i] = dict[key];
        } else {
            result[key] = words[i];
        }
        line = line " " words[i];
    }
    print substr(line, 2);
}
END {
    count = asorti(result, sorted);
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        print result[sorted[i]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! Works very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I had a bit of a crack, but will explain issues:

1. If you have multiple changes in pattern.txt that can pertain to a single line, the first change will make its change and the second will not (eg. Barcelona;Barcln and Hall of Barcelona;HllOfBarcln, obviously if Barcln has already been done when you get to the longer version it will not longer exist and so no change made)
2. Similar to above, there is no abbreviation for the word 'Hall' so again if we assume above is true and only the first change was made, your new file for changes will include hall as not having an abbreviation

`#!/usr/bin/awk -f`

```
BEGIN{
    FS = ";"

    IGNORECASE = 1
}

FNR == NR{
    abbr[tolower($1)] = $2
    next
}

FNR == 1{ FS = " " }

{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++){
        item = tolower($i)
        if(!(item in abbr) && !(item in twa)){
            twa[item]
            print item > "terms_without_abbreviations.txt"
        }
    }

    for(i in abbr)
        gsub("\\<"i"\\>", abbr[i])

    print > "new_terms.txt"

}
```

There are probably other gotchas to look for but it is a vague direction.  Not sure how you would get around my points above??

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both solutions worked for me! Yours and Michaels. I was testing a lot of examples and your approach I understand immediately, but didn't worked at first. After decide to use `gawk` it worked very well! You are right in your assumptions and I also had to face those problems. The term is always in the first column. So far this term occur in terms.txt should be replaced. Using `awk` in the first try, I didn't get the expected result, but it was logic to me, so I tried to use then `gawk` and then I get the expected result. Thank you very much, I did learn a lot from you!