# Using a .csv file as a data pool for the sed function

Tags: bash, perl, csv, sed

I have a large amount of text that I would like to use sed on to do a mass substitution using a .csv file as the data pool for sed to reference.  For instance if I wanted to create a .csv file that looks like:

```
bird,snake
tree,bush
river,stream
```

Then I want use sed to search my text for column 1 strings and replace with column 2 values. Is this something that would best be done with a bash script calling sed, or would I have more success using a Perl script?

Comment: Did you take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read help on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [replace string in a file with value from another file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079883/replace-string-in-a-file-with-value-from-another-file), where you should be able to find an answer

Comment: I did not take the tour, but I will when I am able.

Comment: @martin That linked question is not a duplicate.  It refers specifically to translating one field in a csv file via the info contained in a second csv file.  The text being translated here is not isolated to a specific field, and so those solutions don't apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Perl. Read the CSV file into a hash, build a regular expression from the hash keys, and do a global subtitution on the text using the hash to translate.

It looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my $str = <<'__END_TEXT__';
The ripple-necked bird sang melodies by the curling river while
the hooded tiger glowered in the tree beneath her, just out of reach.
__END_TEXT__

open my $fh, '<', 'words.csv';
my %patterns = map {
   chomp;
   split /,/, $_, 2;
} <$fh>;

my $re = join '|', sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %patterns;

$str =~ s/\b($re)\b/$patterns{$1}/g;

say $str;
```

**output**

```
The ripple-necked snake sang melodies by the curling stream while
the hooded tiger glowered in the bush beneath her, just out of reach.
```

Comment: What if I want to perform this task with single letters?  For instance turn the letter a into "oo" and the letter e into "i" so that snake -> snooki ?

Comment: If you're looking for strings (of any length) *within* the words then you need to remove the `\b` anchors from the regex. They match *word boundaries* and so prevent the pattern from matching anything less than a complete word.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably best done by have one `sed` script convert the mapping file into a second `sed` script that is then applied to the data to be transformed.  Since you say `bash`, I will assume you have [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) available.  If you don't, then either upgrade `bash` or use temporary files instead.

```
sed -i .bak -f <(sed 's%^ *\([^ ,]\{1,\}\), *\([^ ]\{1,\}\) *$%s/\1/\2/g%' \
                      control-file) \
    datefile-1 datafile-2 ...
```

The regex is rather complex because the control data shown in the question has leading blanks and maybe trailing blanks and has a comma-space as the field separator.  It the data in the control file was formatted in a more orthodox fashion:

```
bird,snake
tree,bush
river,stream
```

the code could be simpler:

```
sed -i .bak -f <(sed 's%\([^,]*\),\(.*\)%s/\1/\2/g%' control-file) \
    datefile-1 datafile-2 ...
```

Comment: Observation: the original version of the question had a more complex looking CSV file with multiple leading blanks, a word, a comma, a space, and possibly trailing blanks.  The question was later edited (by someone other than the OP) to remove the leading blanks and the blank after the comma, thus changing the complexity of the answer.  As demonstrated, the problem is solvable using `sed`; it is also solvable using Perl (because one of the intended uses of Perl was as a `sed`-killer — hence the `s2p` command distributed with Perl — but the killing has not been 100% successful).