# Rewrite sed command to edit stream instead of file

Tags: bash, shell, sed

In a normal case, `sed` can edit the stream from another command simply by piping:

```
./somecommand | sed 's/xx/yy/g'
```

However, the `sed` command I'm using is a little complex. Previously, I had gotten help with optimizing `sed` for a specific use case:
[Optimize shell script for multiple sed replacements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563024/optimize-shell-script-for-multiple-sed-replacements)

The eventual outcome was that for my use case, the following `sed` command was the most optimal:

```
./somecommand > file
sed -e 's/^/s|/; s/$/|g/;' replacement_list | sed -r -f - -i file
```

Basically, the first `sed` command creates a list of sed operations from a file with pairs of substitions. The second `sed` command then uses the stream via piping and utilises the `-f` option to process the file.

Things have changed a little since and now I've manage to get `somecommand` to output results in `stdout` instead of writing to a file, but I can't think of a way to rewrite the above set of commands correctly. Part of the difficulty is that the second `sed` command is already using the stream from the first `sed` command.

One thing I've tried is to assign the `stdout` of `somecommand` to a variable and attempt to `<<<` it into the second `sed` command. However, that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around this by using inline expansion of the shell (I think that's what it's called, correct me if I'm wrong).

```
./somecommand | sed -r -e "`sed -e 's/^/s|/; s/$/|g/;' replacement_list`"
```

Note the backticks inside the double quotes, this will cause the stdout of the inner `sed` command to be placed inside the double quotes.

Although, this is dangerous so you might want to try saving the output of the inner `sed` command to a shell variable first like this

```
sedcommand="`sed -e 's/^/s|/; s/$/|g/;' replacement_list`"
./somecommand | sed -r -e "$sedcommand"
```

Comment: `./somecommand | sed -r -e "$( sed -e 's/^/s|/; s/$/|g/;' replacement_list )"` no more need of escape inside double quote or use double quote instead of simple or any multi occurence os backslash like `s/\\\\/\\\\\\\\/g`