# Optimize sed for multiple replacements

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a file, `users.txt`, with words like,

```
user1
user2
user3
```

I want to find these words in another file, `data.txt` and add a prefix to it. `data.txt` has nearly 500K lines. For example, `user1` should be replaced with `New_user1` and so on. I have written simple shell script like

```
for user in `cat users.txt`
do
    sed -i 's/'${user}'/New_&/' data.txt
done
```

For ~1000 words, this program is taking minutes to process, which surprised me because sed is very fast when to comes to find and replace. I tried to refer to [Optimize shell script for multiple sed replacements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563024/optimize-shell-script-for-multiple-sed-replacements), but still not much improvement was observed.

Is there any other way to make this process faster?

Answer (score 5):

Sed is known to be very fast (probably only worse than C).

Instead of `sed 's/X/Y/g' input.txt`, try `sed '/X/ s/X/Y/g' input.txt`. The latter is known to be faster.

Since you only have a "one line at a time semantics", you could run it with `parallel` (on multi-core cpu-s) like this:

```
cat huge-file.txt | parallel --pipe sed -e '/xxx/ s/xxx/yyy/g'
```

If you are working with plain ascii files, you could speed it up by using "C" locale:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -i -e '/xxx/ s/xxx/yyy/g' huge-file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It really helped :)

Answer (score 3):

You can turn your `users.txt` into sed commands like this:

```
$ sed 's|.*|s/&/New_&/|' users.txt 
s/user1/New_user1/
s/user2/New_user2/
s/user3/New_user3/
```

And then use this to process `data.txt`, either by writing the output of the previous command to an intermediate file, or with process substitution:

```
sed -f <(sed 's|.*|s/&/New_&/|' users.txt) data.txt
```

Your approach goes through all of `data.txt` for every single line in `users.txt`, which makes it slow.

If you can't use process substitution, you can use

```
sed 's|.*|s/&/New_&/|' users.txt | sed -f - data.txt
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer Benjamin :). I have tried this approach but still it takes nearly 1 min to finish for ~1000 entries in users.txt

Comment: @user3150037 I don't think you can get much faster with sed - it still has to go through all of `data.txt` and try all substitutions. A faster approach would be to find a pattern that describes all of the words in `users.txt`, then you could work with just one substitution. We'd have to see more of `users.txt` for that, though, with the real data.

Comment: users.txt is real data but with lot of entries and data.txt has also similar data but users range is very high (~500K).

Comment: @user3150037 Then I don't think sed can get you anything much faster. Awk or Perl are often faster.

Comment: How about conflicting names line jami, ben and benjamin ?

Comment: @WalterA Depends on the actual contents of `users.txt` and `data.txt` - could use word boundary anchors or the like if I knew how they appear in each.

Answer (score 1):

Or.. in one go, we can do something like this. Let us say, we have a data file with 500k lines.

```
$>    
wc -l data.txt
500001 data.txt

$>    
ls -lrtha data.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 16M Oct  5 00:25 data.txt

$>
head -2 data.txt  ; echo ; tail -2 data.txt
0|This is a test file maybe
1|This is a test file maybe

499999|This is a test file maybe
500000|This is a test file maybe
```

Let us say that our users.txt has 3-4 keywords, which are to be prefixed with "ab_", in the file "data.txt"

```
$>    
cat users.txt
file
maybe
test
```

So we want to read users.txt and for every word, we want to change that word to a new word. For ex., "file" to "ab_file", "maybe" to "ab_maybe"..

We can run a while loop, read the input words to be prefixed one by one, and then we run a perl command over the file with the input word stored in a variable. In below example, read word is passed to perl command as $word.

I timed this task and this happens fairly quickly. Did it on my VM hosted on my windows 10 (using Centos7).

```
time cat users.txt |while read word; do  perl -pi -e "s/${word}/ab_${word}/g" data.txt; done        
real    0m1.973s
user    0m1.846s
sys     0m0.127s
$>    
head -2 data.txt  ; echo ; tail -2 data.txt
0|This is a ab_test ab_file ab_maybe
1|This is a ab_test ab_file ab_maybe

499999|This is a ab_test ab_file ab_maybe
500000|This is a ab_test ab_file ab_maybe
```

In above code, we read the words: test, file, maybe and changed it to ab_test, ab_file, ab_maybe in the data.txt file. head and tail count confirms our operation.

cheers,
Gaurav

Comment: Your formatting makes it very difficult to comprehend your answer.

Comment: Hi, I am so sorry about that. I hope to improve that. This is my first day on stackoverflow site as a proper user. I am learning. Thank you for your comment.

For now, i have removed the extra bold font. Any further suggestions?

Gaurav

Comment: Welcome to SO! Feel at home.

Comment: Thank you blackpen.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation and answer.