# Replace values in fileA if values are in fileB using awk / sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Here are 2 files, and I want to replace values in fileA, from the values in fileB (if present).

The idea is to process fileA line by line and check if the "gene_id" value (column #3) is somewhere in the column #1 of fileB.

In the first line of fileA, the value is found in fileB. So we replace the value in fileA "id1.2" (column #3) by value in fileB "ND1" (column #3). 
In the second line of fileA, the value is not found in fileB. So it doesn't do anything.

The difficulty is also that it's not the exact same pattern between fileA and fileB, but the whole part before the ".2" has to be the same (e.g. id1 in fileB VS "id1.2" in fileA).

Original files:

```
> cat fileA.txt
chr1    gene_id "id1.2";
chr1    gene_id "id2.2";

> cat fileB.txt
id1 protein_coding  ND1 MT
```

Wanted files (extract value in column #3 from fileB and if there's a match, put it in column #3 of fileA) :

```
> cat fileA.txt
chr1    gene_id "ND1";
chr1    gene_id "id2.2";
```

I tried something inspired from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079883/replace-string-in-a-file-with-value-from-another-file), but it's not working (I'm not sure I really understood the meaning of this awk line as it's the first time I'm using this syntax):

```
awk -F ' ' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$3;next}{$3=a[$3];}1' fileB.txt fileA.txt
```

Any help would be more than welcome.

Comment: Not clear, please be more clear how to get your expected output and add more details into you post.

Comment: I added some more explanations, is it better ?

Comment: thanks for adding more info but still not clear how are you comparing the values? They doesn't seem to be equal value from file1 and file2?

Comment: AND please edit your question to include the code that you thought should work. Then we can help correct your understanding of how these tools work. Good luck.

Comment: I simplified the question, add some code, and some more explanations. Hope it's better now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, based on your samples only(change column numbers accordingly as per your real Input_files).

```
awk -v s1="\"" '
FNR==NR{
   a[$1]=$3
   next
}
{
   val=$3
   gsub(/\"|;|\..*/,"",val)
}
(val in a){
   $3=s1 a[val] s1";"
}
1
'  fileb filea | 
   column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

Some months after, I figured out another option that's a bit more understandable for people who are not so used to awk. If it can help someone, I share that here:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="\t";
    while (getline < fileB ){
        geneTable[$1] = $3
        }
        close(fileB)
    }
{
    split($0, geneID, "gene_id \"")
    split(geneID[2], geneID, ".")

    if (geneID[1] in geneTable){
        $2 = "gene_id \"" geneTable[geneID[1]] "\";"
    }
    print $0
}
```

The best way is to store this command in an external file, that we call here `cmd.awk`. To run the script:

```
awk -v fileB="fileB.txt" -f cmd.awk fileA.txt | column -t
```

- The `BEGIN` part is to read the fileB.txt and store the results in the array `geneTable`.
- The `split` part is to get the value after the "gene_id" in fileA.txt.
- The `if` part is to replace value in fileA.txt if found in the array `geneTable` (=> found in fileB.txt)